# POST function for REST service returns empty response

Tags: android, rest, http-post

I'm trying to do a post method for a REST service, but I'm not getting any response from server:

```
public JSONObject postValues (String strUrl, String strJsonArray) throws Exception{
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    strJsonArray = "data=" + strJsonArray;

    Log.e("result",""+strJsonArray);

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(strJsonArray.getBytes());
    os.flush();

    conn.connect();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e("output",output);
        sb.append(output);

    }

    Log.e("output",sb.toString());
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

    conn.disconnect();

    return jsonObject;

}
```

When I see my logCat a get:

```
output {}
```

I know that the server is working right because I'm using the "advanced REST client" plugin of google chrome. If I call the URL manually (using the plugin of course)I get the desired answer:

```
{"message":"OK","code":200}
```

But if I try to use my function, my strJsonArray is inserted but I get an empty respond from server.

Is there anything wrong with my code?.

Comment: Everything looks good... You could use Wireshark to capture the packets sent to and received from the server using an emulator and the chrome rest client. Then you can compare them and maybe find out what's wrong. You could also check if theres something in the error stream (`conn.getErrorStream()`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're right. There is nothing wrong with the code. The problem is in the server. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Alright :) I just posted the comment as an answer, so that you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good...

You could use Wireshark to capture the packets sent to and received from the server using an emulator and the chrome rest client. Then you can compare them and maybe find out what's wrong.

You could also check if theres something in the error stream (`conn.getErrorStream()`).